# How to use cURLpp/libcurl with Visual C++ 2008 Express

Tags: windows, visual-c++, curl, openssl, curlpp

I've downloaded cURLpp, libcurl and openSSL. I'm a complete beginner and I want to use cURL with my c++ program. Every doc I can find about getting started is written for Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a short or quickly answered question. I would recommend you instead ask specific questions about problems you encounter.

However, here's a PDF guide on how to build libcurl using MSVC 2008:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2008.pdf

Comment: Since cURL was so easy to use with PHP and the Windows command line, I didn't think that installing it for use with Visual C++ would get so involved. I guess that was just wishful thinking. Thanks for the guide, I will try it out and come back with any problems I encounter. Thanks!

Comment: It would have been great if someone had warned me that I have to download 2 other applications, and 2 other libraries before I can build curl. Ok 2 be fair most linux distros may allready have the libs... Sounds simple enough.