# How to install cURLpp in Windows?

Tags: c++, libcurl, curlpp

Complete newbie here, as you most probably guessed by my previous post. I can't seem to find anything on this, and I have never installed a library before. my previous question was answered with telling me to install and use libcurl, and that cURLpp is a wrapper for C++, so naturally I assumed that cURLpp was the way to go. So, how do I install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use cURLpp/libcurl with Visual C++ 2008 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356249/how-to-use-curlpp-libcurl-with-visual-c-2008-express)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is quite old, but I will share what has worked in my experience.

OS: MS Windows 10 (64 bit)

I'm using MSYS2 MinGW GCC compiler and tools, so I assume mingw-gcc, mingw-cmake, mingw-make, and mingw-curl are already installed in the system and msys2/mingw64/bin is in your PATH.

In a terminal, follow these steps:

Step 1)
`git clone git@github.com:jpbarrette/curlpp.git`

Step 2)
`cd curlpp`

Step 3)
`mkdir build`

Step 4)
`cd build`

Step 5)
`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF`

Step 6)
`cmake --build .`

After this, in your `curlpp/build` you will find the files `libcurlpp.a`, `libcurlpp.dll.a`, and `libcurlpp.dll`. Now you need to add `libcurlpp.dll.a` to your linker settings (remember to add `libcurl.dll.a` too, because it is a dependency of libcurlpp).

Finally, you can compile your program, and it should work. If you receive a message saying libcurlpp.dll is not found, copy the `libcurlpp.dll` next to your binary.