# Making curlpp work in Windows 10

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2013, curlpp

I upgraded to Windows 10 and am trying to make curlpp work with MS visual studio 2013. I have downloaded the first simple example from github:

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>


using namespace curlpp::options;

int main(int, char **)
{
try
{
    // That's all that is needed to do cleanup of used resources (RAII style).
    curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

    // Our request to be sent.
    curlpp::Easy myRequest;

    // Set the URL.
    myRequest.setOpt<Url>("http://example.com");

    // Send request and get a result.
    // By default the result goes to standard output.
    myRequest.perform();
}

catch(curlpp::RuntimeError & e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

catch(curlpp::LogicError & e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

  return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to go about solving this? I have added in the additional include directories the directories of curl and curlpp, however when I build the program I get 26 errors and 18 warnings. This answer [How to use cURLpp/libcurl with Visual C++ 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356249/how-to-use-curlpp-libcurl-with-visual-c-2008-express) suggests that doing it for MS Visual studio might be quite a pain, so I would have no problem switching to another compiler or IDE for this project.

To help clarify, most errors I get are of the form: curlpp::x::z definition of dllimport function not allowed.

Comment: Typically there is some symbol that governs whether the header defines a function as dllimport or dllexport. I don't think this has anything to do with Windows 10.

Comment: The answer to this question has 116 words. How useful is this? About as useful as your "26 errors and 18 warnings".